# How to get my visualforce page apex code through rest api?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I want to get my visualforce page apex code through rest API. I tried metadata API like /services/data/v41.0/sobjects/{sobjectName}/describe/layouts and I am able to access fields information but I want to access apex code of the page where define all fields and triggers.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the body of Apex classes (that aren't part of managed packages) from a query on the `ApexClass` standard object:

```
curl \
-H 'X-PrettyPrint: 1' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <session-id>' \
https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Body+FROM+ApexClass+LIMIT+1
```

Visualforce pages can be retrieved similarly through a query on the `ApexPage` standard object to retrieve the `Markup`:

```
curl \
-H 'X-PrettyPrint: 1' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <session-id>' \
https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Markup+FROM+ApexPage+LIMIT+1
```

For more information on available standard fields and objects to query, check out the [Object Reference](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/object_reference.pdf)

Comment: Thanks martin for sharing helpful document.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make 2 api calls i.e. first to get vf page code and second to get controller code.

IF testing on workbench, use end point url as:

`/services/data/v43.0/tooling/query?q=select+id,ControllerKey,Markup+from+apexpage+where+name='<pagename>'`

Response will give you controller name in `ControllerKey` node.

Now, next call Apex class using end point as:

`/services/data/v43.0/tooling/query?q=select+id,body,name+from+apexclass+where+name='<ControllerKey value>'`

If apex class is used as extensions then you have to parse the markup from first response to get the class name.

Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Thanks Sumit Its very helpful. You saved my lot of time .

Comment: Hi Sumit, I need custom label information which is used in apex page like {!$Label.MyCustomLabel} . Please share query for getting this.

Comment: Hi Shubham, please raise new question and share the link, as this question is closed.